# Regex to extract words except optional final word

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need a regex to extract building names from a list. I'm passing the text and a regex to a framework that does the parsing, so I really want to try to solve this with a regex, not code.

The building name is always all caps and preceded by "Building:" then followed by any of (a) a number, (b) the word "UNIT" in all caps, or (c) any mixed case word. Thus I want to get BUILDING ONE as the result from all of the following except the last row, which should return nothing:

```
Building: BUILDING ONE 15 [building name followed by unit number]
Optional preceding text Building: BUILDING ONE 15 [preceding text, then building name followed unit number]
Building: BUILDING ONE UNIT 15 [building name followed by word UNIT and unit number]
Building: BUILDING ONE Floor 2 [building name followed by mixed case word]
Grounds: OPEN SPACE WEST Section 3 [not a building - return nothing]
```

I feel like I know this, but having a brain block. The closest I am right now is `^.*Building:\s([A-Z+\s*]*).*` which for the samples above returns

```
BUILDING ONE
BUILDING ONE
BUILDING ONE UNIT
BUILDING ONE F
```

The application doing the parsing is written in Python, but as mentioned above, I'm just passing in the regex and data.

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: something like this: `(?<=Building: )BUILDING [A-Z]+(?= (?:\d+|UNIT|[A-Z][a-z]))`, see https://regex101.com/r/cb7Qto/1

Comment: @Mark - the application is Python

Comment: In a comment you posted on @Nick's answer you said you could not use lookbehinds. Don't you think that is highly relevant and therefore should be stated in the question? Readers should not be expected to read all comments on the question and all the answers to understand the question. You should also add a tag indicating what language you are using as different languages have regex engines with varying features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
(?<=Building: )[A-Z]+(?: (?!UNIT\b)[A-Z]+\b)*
```

This matches:

- `(?<=Building: )` : positive lookbehind for `Building:`
- `[A-Z]+` : an uppercase word
- `(?: (?!UNIT\b)[A-Z]+\b)*` : zero or more uppercase words that are not `UNIT`

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hEpnxh/1)

If you're using a flavour of regex that doesn't support lookbehinds, you could use this similar regex, which captures the building name in group 1:

```
\bBuilding: ([A-Z]+(?: (?!UNIT\b)[A-Z]+\b)*)
```

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/D0kCfV/2)

Comment: You nailed it - I don't have lookbehinds available, so your second example is exactly it. Thanks!

Comment: @CarySwoveland agreed - I just copied that part from OPs original regex. I've edited with your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can match the regular expression

```
\bBuilding: +((?:[A-Z]+ )*[A-Z]+)(?<!\bUNIT)(?= +(?:(?:UNIT +)?\d|(?![A-Z]+\b)[a-zA-Z]+ +\d))
```

The building name, if there is a match, is held in capture group 1.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tT5WVk/1)

---

If the regex engine supports `\K` (start the match at the current location and discard all previously-consumed characters), one can
write

```
\bBuilding: +\K(?:[A-Z]+ )*[A-Z]+(?<!\bUNIT)(?= +(?:(?:UNIT +)?\d|(?![A-Z]+\b)[a-zA-Z]+ +\d))
```

in which case the building name will be matched (i.e., there is no capture group).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PvMV7S/1)

---

It appears that rule that the building name can be followed by a mixed-case word cannot be fully implemented. Consider, for example, the text

```
"Building: BUILDING ONE FLOOR 2"
```

As `"FLOOR"` is not mixed case `BUILDING ONE"` cannot be identified as the building name. However, because the building name could be followed by a unit number we would conclude that the building name is `"BUILDING ONE FLOOR"`. The best we could do is to say the building name can be followed by a word that contains a lowercase letter (followed by a digit), which is what I have done.

---

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
\bBuilding:[ ]+   # match 'Building:' preceded by a word boundary
                  # and followed by one or more spaces
(                 # begin capture group 1
  (?:[A-Z]+ )     # match one or more uppercase letters followed by a space
                  # in a non-capture group
  *               # match the above non-capture group zero or more times
  [A-Z]+          # match one or more uppercase letters
)                 # end capture group 1
(?<!\bUNIT)       # negative lookbehind asserts that the current location cannot
                  # be preceded by 'UNIT' preceded by a word boundary
(?=               # begin positive lookahead 
  [ ]+            # match one or more spaces
  (?:             # begin non-capture group
    (?:UNIT +)?   # optionally ('?') match 'UNIT' followed by one or more spaces
    \d            # match a digit
  |               # or
    (?![A-Z]+\b)  # negative lookahead asserts that the current location is
                  # not followed by one or more uppercase letters
    [a-zA-Z]+ +   # match one or more letters followed by one or more spaces
    \d            # match a digit
  )               # end non-capture group
)                 # end positive lookahead
```

In the above I put some space characters in a character class `[ ]` to make them visible.

Comment: @Nick, thanks, I fixed it as you did yours, by adding a capture group.